# error embedding a war into a jetty

Tags: java, deployment, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I tried [this example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Setting_a_Web_Application_Context) of an embedding war into a jetty.
When I debug on eclipse everything its ok and the webservices is deployed fine in port 8080, but when I make a jar with this program and put into a server (I tried into a tomcat 5.5 and into a jetty 7.4.1) when I start the program, when I started the jetty server appears this exception:

```
7641 [qtp21021313-35] ERROR configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet  - Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
7641 [qtp21021313-35] WARN configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet  - Unable to load/create servlet engine config file, attempting internal default (from jar).
```

Only the default webservices methos are deployed (AdminService and Version)
The wsdd its fine. If I deploy this war into a server it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You should run the java code without the servlet container (Tomcat/Jetty), you have the jetty server embedded, that's why in eclipse the code works fine.

Jetty's slogan: 
*"Don't deploy your application in Jetty, deploy Jetty in your application."*

You should check this tutorial:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

For more info:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications

Comment: thanks Miguel for your answer.
But, when I put my code into a tomcat/jetty, the thing that I'm trying to do is make it available to download with java web start. You know, the code compressed into a .jar and with a .jnlp that calls the .jar and the other libs

Comment: Use osgi service to download all bundles of your app (jetty bundle in this case).